# Drywall vs hardiebacker

Tags: drywall, tile

I am doing a bathroom remodel down to the studs. The wall behind the sink will be tiled with stacked splitface marble. My questiom: what goes on the wall before the tile?  do I drywall, then add the hardiebacker on top, or just attach hardiebacker? I ask because then I have to know exactly where the drywall would end and hardiebacker would start, which is dependent on cabinets and counter top etc. Or, I just drywall everything and add hardiebacker once exact perimeter of tile is known. Or is hardiebacker even needed. Could tile go on drywall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HardieBacker on the studs, no drywall. In this zone the tile will hold better and last longer. Outside the damp or wet area, I change to green or blue board - a water-resistant type of sheetrock that I use in bathrooms. I will use HardieBacker for the width of the sink to the next stud, or in a tub / shower area, then green or blue water resistant sheetrock.

I have seen water-resistant sheetrock hold up for 30 years and even regular sheetrock for 20 or close with well-sealed tile. I have never had a quality cement board fail or need repair so this is the best in my opinion.

Comment: Good advice, but check with your permits office. One of our jurisdictions requires denshield in bathrooms.